# MySQL update query using indexed column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `table1` and the columns are like this:

```
id - int
field1 - varchar(10)
field2 - varchar(10)
totalMarks - int
```

Also, I have created an index using the column `field1`.

```
create index myindex1 on table1 (field1);
```

I need to update the table entries, either using `field1` or `field2`.

```
UPDATE table1 SET totalMarks = 1000 WHERE field1='somevalue';
```

or

```
UPDATE table1 SET totalMarks = 1000 WHERE field2='somevalue';
```

Which update query will have good performance? Since we have created an index using `field1`, will it have a good performance if we use `field1` in the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `update` statement with a `where` clause with an equality comparison on an indexed column should use the index for the `where` clause.

This will not *always* improve performance, but it usually will on larger tables.  On very small tables where the data all fits on a single data page, the engine needs to load both the index and the data page into memory, which can actually be a wee bit slower than just looking for the row on a given page.  This is an edge case.

I would recommend using the version with the indexed column.